# creating a log file using windows api C++

Tags: windows, file, winapi, visual-c++

I have written a code to write some values in a text file using CreateFile API
        But when i execute the code sometimes the values logged are correct but
 sometimes they are just wierd symbols.I cannot figure what is the problem.Please tell me what wrong in my code.
                  thanks in advance

```
#pragma  once
#define  max_threads 5
#define  buf_size 255
#include "7febdll_varnum.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <assert.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <tchar.h>
const wchar_t* MUTEXNAME = L"Example Mutex";
    }
```

I am giving inputs like

```
void main()
{
    varunthread::fvarunthread::myfn("varun /n%d%d mehta /n deepanshu goyal /n",1,2);
    varunthread::fvarunthread::myfn("varunmehta2/n");
    varunthread::fvarunthread::myfn("varunmehta3");
}
```

Comment: .but I'll start..  Don't create a new thread for every log write.  Just create one thread once that loops round a producer-consumer queue.  If the queue needs a mutex to protect it, the correct way to wait on a mutex is to use the wait API's like 'WaitForSingleObject()'.  If you want some clever formatting stuff, encapsulate it in a 'logData' class and queue class instances to the write thread.

Comment: If you need to learn about multiThreading and inter-thread comms, it's best to not cut your teeth on an urgent deliverable.  After some experience, it's not that difficult to write reliable an effective threaded stuff, but you have to get past the 'catastrophically wrong' stage first.

Comment: Can u tell me what is wrong in the code as when i am using these same winapi in a simple smaller program the output is absolutely fine.

Comment: It's not right because of your misuse of mutexes and spawning of multiple threads.

Comment: @hardyz009 - Google for 'WaitForSingleObject'

Comment: Can you help me with this code i suck at mutex nd threading nd not bale to understand them also

Comment: @hardyz009 - I do have to give you full marks for actually implemementing something and getting it to work at all.  If you use a Windows wait function, like WaitForSingleObject(), to wait on the mutex, your code may work inefficiently, but correctly.  You do not need to open the mutex in each thread - just pass in the mutex handle and wait on it.  If there is only one process writing to the file the mutex does not need a name, (and, in fact, can be replaced with the faster 'Critical Section').

Comment: @hardyz009 two words: ___write english___ Can't you write "and" entirely and proofread your comments? You're not begging for help with a 5 years old's write-style

Comment: @MartinJames i have tried using mutexes also and that helped me a lot as now atleast my string values are not jumbling but even by using mutexes some values are being skipped For eg WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
//between these two line i had placed the 
WriteFIle and CreateFile

 ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

Now you tell me have i placed the mutexes at correct place or i need to place it near the CreaThread function Please help me

Comment: @Eregrith i am new to this site so dont know the posting rules in details

Comment: @hardyz009 - you are obviously making progress!  Edit your post to show your latest code.

Comment: @MartinJames Edited the code, added the MUTEX part.But Still Not working

Comment: That looks a bit better. The WFSO and release will serialize access to the file.  You should check, in the write thread, that the file has been opened OK - CreateFile can fail, so check the returned hFile for INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: @MartinJames i edited the code and checked the hFile,and i got no error regarding opening of the file.Did i check at the right place??

Comment: @hardyz009 - HEY!  You are passing 'lpLogString' into each thread as a CreateThread() parameter, (correct!), but not retreiving it in the write thread!  You have to retrieve the string data in each write thread using 'LPVOID lpParam', else there will be big problems.

Comment: @MartinJames retrieve as in how you mean to say somthing like 
lpParam=lpLogString;
and then passing this lpParam into the writefile

Comment: You were so close!  You started off corectly, creating a unique string, 'lpLogString=new TCHAR[]', for each write.  You even correctly passed it to the write thread, 'CreateThread(..,lpLogString,..);', and then.. you forgot about it in the write thread!  The 'LPVOID lpParam' in the write thread is a pointer to your TCHAR array - you must cast it back somehow, (I'm not familiar with TCHAR arrays), to a local variable, write it and then dispose it  Don't touch lpLogString in the write thread!!  Call you local something else, 'TCHAR *lpLocalTCHAR[]' or something like that.

Comment: @MartinJames i edited the code now in the writefile function i replaced lpLogString with lpParam. And when u said cast back lpParam where exactly you meant it

if you meant to cast back the lpParam in the writefile api
something like this  (TCHAR)lpParam  then this cannot be done as it gives me a type casting error

Comment: 'i replaced lpLogString with lpParam.' - that may be enough!  The WriteFile() doesn't care about the pointer much, it just writes from it :)  OK, now the problem is the number of bytes to write.  You cannot get it from 'int iLogStringLength=result.size();' - you have to get it from the lpParam.

Comment: but we have to just give the number of bytes and if we get it from result it would be same as if getting from lpParam as it is "result" which is passed to "lpLogString" adn then to lpParam

Comment: @hardyz009 - no. When the write thread gets to read result to get the length, it may well have been overwritten by another log request. 'lpLogString' in the CreateThread call is not passed directly to 'lpParam' in the thread function - it is signaled to it. By the time the write thread actually runs, 'lpLogString', 'result' etc. may have been overwritten many times.  Only lpParam may be read safely by the write thread.  If it was safe to read the result variable, why do you bother to create a new, unique lpLogString for every write thread, (ans: because you know it's going to be overwritten!).

Comment: @MartinJames yes you are right.But how to get length of lpParam .I cannot use sizeof. I tried to check the function by passing a default length to check if really the issue is with length and it worked correct the issue is with length.
But with the default length specified the values are not written in the order they are entered they get jumbled

Comment: @hardyz009 - well, it's like C strings, I guess.  Is there some sort of 'strlen()' function that can return the length of the TCHARs pointed to by lpParam?

Comment: @hardyz009 - I'm afraid there's more.  'fvarunthread::myfn' is not thread-safe because of the unprotected instance members like 'result' and 'lpLogString'.  Don't call 'fvarunthread::myfn' from more than one thread.

Comment: @hardyz009 - or, failing that, you should do it right and define a 'threadComms' class that can hold the data, its length, the mutex handle and anything else that turns up.  Create an instance with new(), load it up, pass its pointer to the thread as the CreateThread parameter.  In the write thread, cast the lpParam back to a 'threadComms *', lock the mutex handle, write the data, release the mutex and dispose() the 'threadComms *'.

Comment: @MartinJames exactly what i need to do i am so much confused in this c++ threading i am out of my wits now

Comment: @hardyz009 - I mean, you're already creating an new TCHAR array each time, so why not create a 'threadComms' class instance instead?   You can then pass anything you like into the thread safely.  Just do it.  It's like medicine, you'll feel much better afterwards, honest :)

Comment: @MartinJames but martin even if i create a class that would not solve my problem because the code would be the same.My code has two problems one is getting the number of bytes to be written secondly interthread communication,and i am not able to do both of these since so many days

Comment: @hardyz009 - no.  A class instance pointer would allow you to communicate the string data, its length, the hMutex handle and anything else you need to the thread in a safe manner, ie. without the write threads needing to read any varunthread namespace/instance variables like 'result' after they have been overwritten.  Something like I posted in my answer.

Comment: @hardyz009 - you could add a constructor that takes the 'result' string as a parameter and then does that TCHAR allocation and size-getting.

Comment: @MartinJames hmmm i will have to work on that and change my entire code all together.Can there be a sloution the way i am doing it

Comment: @hardyz009 - not if you try to access namespace globals and/or instance variables from threads that will likely run long after the data has been overwritten.  Create a unique class instance or malloc a unique struct, load it up with everything needed by the write thread and pass its pointer in as the CreateThread parameter.  Thse write threads may not actually run for 100ms!  'result' etc. are sure to be overwritten by new log requests.  Create something unique, load it up and pass it to the thread so that the thread does not have to access anything else to work correctly.

Comment: @MartinJames can you please post the entire code i am not able to do it pleaseeee

Comment: You can do this!  Define a class, create an instance with new(), load it up with data, pass its pointer to the thread.  In the thread, cast it back, lock th mutex, write out the data, release the mutex, dispose the instance.  That's it.  You already have most of the code!

Comment: @MartinJames ok i will surely try it u have given me the entire idea.If i am not able to will ask you for some mroe help thank you very much

Comment: @hardyz009 I added a bit to my answer, just to give a rough idea of the inter-thread comms.

Comment: @hardyz009 varun thread varun thread

Answer (score 3):

Import a log class that already works OK.

Failing that, start to fix your code by using a Windows wait function to wait on the mutex.  If you Google for 'WaitForSingleObject', you should be able to use it easily enough - you need to pass the mutex handle into every thread so that they can wait on it.  You can obviously write code well enough, you just need more experience with threading, signaling and inter-thread comms.

Oh - look at the lifetime of 'lpLogString' - where is it disposed?  I have not used TCHAR but, AFAIK, everything that is newed should be disposed.  I'm guessing that it should be disposed in the write thread after writing it to the file.

You seriously need to refactor your whole design to use just one thread that waits on a queue for stuff.  Creating new threads for each write is grossly inefficient and is likely to lead to a somewhat indeterminate write order since the order in which threads get the mutex is not guaranteed to be FIFO.

You are passing 'lpLogString' into each thread as a CreateThread() parameter, (correct!), but not retreiving it in the write thread! You have to retrieve the string data in each write thread using 'LPVOID lpParam', else there will be big problems.

..which leads, eventually, to the thought 'with all this passing of data to threads via only one pointer, I may as well declare a class that can contain the Format string, mutex handle and anything else that comes up.  I can then create one, load it up and pass its pointer to the thread. It could contain all those special formatting commands and code as methods - the write thread could then do all that formatting so that my main app doesn't have to.  The thread can dispose() of the 'thread comms' instance later, when it's finished with it.

..which leads, eventually, to the thought 'now I have this 'thread comms' class, I could queue instances of it to one thread on a producer-consumer queue instead of continually creating new threads.  I could pass the instance of the producer-consumer queue to the thread in that LPVOID lpParam thing'.

// in header:

```
   class ThreadComms {
    private:
    public:
      int dataLen;
      TCHAR *lpLogString;
      HANDLE hMutex;
      ThreadComms(String data);
      ~ThreadComms();
    };
```

// in cpp

```
ThreadComms::ThreadComms(String data){
    dataLen=data.Length();
    lpLogString=new TCHAR[dataLen+1];
    strcpy(( char *)lpLogString,(char *)data.c_str());
};

ThreadComms::~ThreadComms(){
  delete(lpLogString);
};

    HANDLE hthread;
    DWORD dwthreadid;
    DWORD _stdcall MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        ThreadComms *inThreadComms=(ThreadComms *)lpParam;

        DWORD dwNumBytesWritten = 0;
        HANDLE hFile;
        WaitForSingleObject(inThreadComms->hMutex,INFINITE);
        hFile = CreateFile(FILENAME,
                            FILE_APPEND_DATA,
                            FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_ALWAYS,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL);

         WriteFile(hFile,
                    (char *)inThreadComms->lpLogString,
                    inThreadComms->dataLen,
                    (LPDWORD)&dwNumBytesWritten,
                    NULL );

        CloseHandle( hFile );
        ReleaseMutex(inThreadComms->hMutex);
        delete(inThreadComms);
    }

    void myfn(const String inMess)
    {
        HANDLE hMutex;
        hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"");
        assert(hMutex!=NULL);
        ThreadComms *threadComms=new(ThreadComms)(inMess);

        CreateThread(NULL,
                                0,
                                MyThreadFunction,
                                threadComms,
                                0,
                                &dwthreadid);
        CloseHandle(hthread);
    }
```

..or, better example that works, (at least, it does in C++ Builder):

// in header:

```
    class PCqueue{
    private:
        CRITICAL_SECTION access;
        deque<void*> *objectQueue;
        HANDLE queueSema;
    public:
        PCqueue();
        void push(void *ref);
        bool pop(void**ref,DWORD timeout);
    };

   class ThreadComms {
    private:
    public:
      int dataLen;
      TCHAR *lpLogString;
      ThreadComms(String data);
      ~ThreadComms();
    };

  class ThreadLogger {
    private:
        PCqueue *queue;
        HANDLE logThread;
        HANDLE fileAccess;
        AnsiString Ffilename;
        static DWORD _stdcall staticThreadRun(void *param){
            ((ThreadLogger*)param)->threadRun(0);
        };
    public:
        void threadRun(void *param);
        ThreadLogger(String filename);
        void logString(String data);
  };
```

// in cpp:

```
PCqueue::PCqueue(){
    objectQueue=new deque<void*>;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&access);
    queueSema=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,MAXINT,NULL);
};

void PCqueue::push(void *ref){
    EnterCriticalSection(&access);
    objectQueue->push_front(ref);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&access);
    ReleaseSemaphore(queueSema,1,NULL);
};

bool PCqueue::pop(void **ref,DWORD timeout){
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0==WaitForSingleObject(queueSema,timeout)) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&access);
        *ref=objectQueue->back();
        objectQueue->pop_back();
        LeaveCriticalSection(&access);
        return(true);
    }
    else
        return(false);
};




ThreadComms::ThreadComms(String data){
    dataLen=data.Length();
    lpLogString=new TCHAR[dataLen+1];
    int index=0;
    for(index=0;index<dataLen;index++){lpLogString[index]=data[index+1];};
};

ThreadComms::~ThreadComms(){
  delete(lpLogString);
};


ThreadLogger::ThreadLogger(String filename){
    Ffilename=filename;
    fileAccess=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"Example Mutex");
    queue=new PCqueue();
    logThread=CreateThread(NULL,
                0,
                staticThreadRun,
                this,
                0,
                0);
};

void ThreadLogger::threadRun(void *param){
    ThreadComms *inMess;
    DWORD dummy;
    while(queue->pop((void**)&inMess, INFINITE)){
        HANDLE hFile;
        WaitForSingleObject(fileAccess,INFINITE);
        hFile = CreateFile( &Ffilename[1],
                            FILE_APPEND_DATA,
                            FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_ALWAYS,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL);
         WriteFile(hFile,
                    (char *)inMess->lpLogString,
                    inMess->dataLen,
                    &dummy,
                    NULL );

        CloseHandle( hFile );
        ReleaseMutex(fileAccess);
        delete(inMess);
    };
};


void ThreadLogger::logString(String data){
    ThreadComms *threadComms=new(ThreadComms)(data);
    queue->push(threadComms);
};
```

Comment: martin can you please post the entire code i am not able to do it pleaseeee